# Using shell scripts to remove all commas except for the first on each line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a text file consisting of lines which all begin with a numerical code, followed by one or several words, a comma, and then a list of words separated by commas. I need to delete all commas in every line apart from the first comma. For example:

```
1.2.3 Example question, a, question, that, is, hopefully, not, too, rudimentary

which should be changed to

1.2.3 Example question, a question that is hopefully not too rudimentary
```

I have tried using sed and shell scripts to solve this, and I can figure out how to delete the first comma on each line (1) and how to delete all commas (2), but not how to delete only the commas after the first comma on each line

(1)

```
while read -r line
do
 echo "${line/,/}"
done <"filename.txt" > newfile.txt
mv newfile.txt filename.txt
```

(2)

```
sed 's/,//g'  filename.txt  > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed ':a; s/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\),/\1/;ta' filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

**Details**

- `:a` - sets an `a` label
- `s/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\),/\1/` - finds 0+ non-commas at the start of string, a comma and again 0+ non-commas, capturing this substring into Group 1, and then just matching a `,` and replacing the match with the contents of Group 1 (removes the non-first comma)
- `ta`  - upon a successful replacement, jumps back to the `a` label location.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/gEGMZz):

```sh
s='1.2.3 Example question, a, question, that, is, hopefully, not, too, rudimentary'
sed ':a; s/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\),/\1/;ta' <<< "$s"
# => 1.2.3 Example question, a question that is hopefully not too rudimentary
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture the first comma, and then remove the others.  One option is to change the first comma into some otherwise unused character (<kbd>Control-A</kbd> for example), then remove the remaining commas, and finally replace the replacement character with a comma:

```
sed -e $'s/,/\001/; s/,//g; s/\001/,/'
```

(using Bash [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) — the `\001` maps to Control-A).

An alternative mechanism uses `sed`'s labels and branches, as illustrated by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64885577/15168).

Comment: As the newline is always removed before transferring the current line to the pattern space in sed , it normally (unless introduced by the programmer) will never be in the pattern space. Therefore for GNU sed `sed 's/,/\n/;s///g;s/\n/,/' file` is a safe idiom.

Answer (score 3):

If using GNU `sed`, you can specify a number in the flags of `sed`'s `s///` command along with `g` to indicate which match to start replacing at:

```sh
$ sed 's/,//2g' <<<'1.2.3 Example question, a, question, that, is, hopefully, not, too, rudimentary'
1.2.3 Example question, a question that is hopefully not too rudimentary
```

Its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) says:

> Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the `g` and `NUMBER` modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across `sed` implementations.  For GNU `sed`, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the `NUMBER`th, and then match and replace all matches from the `NUMBER`th on.

so if you're using a different `sed`, your mileage may vary. (OpenBSD and NetBSD `sed`s raise an error instead, for example).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NF>1 {$1=$1","} 1' FS=, OFS= filename.txt
```

```
sed ':a;s/,//2;t a' filename.txt
```

```
sed 's/,/\
/;s/,//g;y/\n/,/' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/&\n/;h;s/,//g;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Append a newline to the first comma.

Copy the current line to the hold space.

Remove all commas in the current line.

Append the current line to the hold space.

Swap the current line for the hold space.

Remove everything between the introduced newlines.